# DB2 Join Query that Maximizes Column

Tags: sql, db2

I am OK at basic SQL, but my understanding fails when it comes to more complex searches.

Right now, I am trying to return records for Location 16.

Most records are empty, so I cannot debug my database application with those records.

```
SELECT
  I.PART_NUM, I.ID, L.SHELF, L.IN_STOCK
FROM
  INVENTORY I
  JOIN LOCATIONS L ON I.ID=L.INV_ID
WHERE
  L.ID=16 AND PART_NUM IN 
  (
    SELECT
      TOP 10 N.PART_NUM
    FROM
      INVENTORY N 
      JOIN LOCATIONS T ON N.ID=T.INV_ID
    WHERE
      T.ID=16
    ORDER BY 
      IN_STOCK
  )
ORDER BY 
      IN_STOCK, I.PART_NUM
```

Developers are not given direct access to the database, but rather make calls using an in-house developed application that permits basic SQL calls.

When I try running the code below, I get the following error:

> ERROR [42601][IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N An unexpected token "10" was found following "DOR IN ( SELECT TOP". Expected tokens may include: "CONCAT".

I wasn't sure if this was a limitation of our in-house developed application or something in DB2.

I went to the SQL Tutorial here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

There, I used the tables they supply to create a similar query:

```
SELECT 
    OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, LastName, FirstName
FROM 
    OrderDetails I 
    JOIN Orders L ON I.OrderID=L.OrderID
WHERE 
    EmployeeID=5 AND OrderDetailID IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            TOP 10 N.OrderDetailID 
        FROM 
            OrderDetails N 
            JOIN Orders T ON N.OrderID=T.OrderID
        WHERE 
            EmployeeID=5
        ORDER BY 
            Quantity
    )
ORDER BY 
    Quantity
```

It gives me a similar error:

> Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "10": syntax error)

### What do I need to do to modify my SQL query to return the Vendors with the most quantity in stock?

I can order the **LOCATIONS** table by the **IN_STOCK** quantity, but then I cannot filter to get **INVENTORY** records that are valid (lots of test data in the database).

Comment: side note: in the event of duplicate in-stock numbers, your query will not return stable results.  Your outer query and inner query imply two different things: the inner one that there's only one row per item (ignores shelf - do you want to total all shelf locations?), and the outer one that there's multiple locations (otherwise you could just do the ordering/row limit in the outer query).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I was trying to find what stores actually had multiple locations. After applying the fix in the answer below, I wound up with an empty data set.

Comment: ...?  How?  Can you post what your modified query looks like?  I'm assuming you now mean you need the top 10 based on the `SUM` of the in-stock quantity (get all shelf locations for the top 10 overall parts, regardless of location)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clause `Select TOP` is not valid on DB2. Intead use

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY id
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Wow. Just Wow. I thought `SELECT TOP x` was standardized SQL. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to know valid syntax for a particular DBMS, your best choice should its reference manual.  I hate to say RTFM, but IMHO it's your best choice. When using DB2 for LUW, you want to look [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0004116.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-6-0), or for your version. The internet is full of people who think SQL means a Microsoft, Oracle, or (whatever they know) product. DB2 (for IBM i) is the most SQL standards compliant of any database, at least according to IBM, and SQL originated from IBM.